# Anyone have this color overlay on Chromium?

Tags: chromium

It doesn't always happen, but happens often enough to be very annoying.

It seems to be connected to Chromium, which is my default browser. I just checked Firefox and there all looks well.

What is showing in the image below is docx attachment, but the problem can also be seen if I use Google docs, if I add things like tables and images. By moving the cursor around on the screen I can get the "overlay" to change its position and sometimes I manage to kill it at least temporarily.

I would be grateful on any hints on how to get rid of this "noise" permanently. Perhaps I have some parameter in Chromium not set correctly? It looks suspiciously like some "feature" which is supposed to help me? If so, I would like to turn it off.

I wanted to see how reprocible the effect is, and to verify it isn't something connected to the display of attachments. I took one of my Google docs and I see the same color triangles (with other colors being used). The shape and number depends upon the zoom I choose to display the information, but they cover up the information I want to read.

The Google doc file had screen shots which I have embedded into the document. I didn't see it on math formulae which I also embedded.

I looked at the Chromium setting, which I think are plain vanilla, and saw nothing special. Is there a "factory reset" to the Chromium settings?

I checked again on Firefox and there all is well. So one solution is to dump Chromium and use Firefox.

The OS is Ubuntu 22.10. Chromium is Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) snap (64-bit) with no extensions added.

In response to a helpful comment, I looked for any hardware accelerations and failed to find any. I did find a factory reset, so I used it to clean out anything I may have entered along the way. I saw that I could get my current settings, so here they are:

Locale: en-GB
User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Chromium: 108.0.5359.124snap
Startup type: Continue where you left off
Homepage: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
Homepage is the New Tab page: No
Show Home button: Yes
Default search engine: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
Extensions: Web Store, Chromium PDF Viewer, Google Hangouts

Basically there is little change after doing the factory reset. The colors are different, the number of triangles is different, but the problem remains. I don't know if it just this machine or if others see a problem.

I see that I was using xorg. This works better with team viewer. Otherwise I use wayland. To be sure I did a log out, log in this time using wayland. Again, no difference.

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that. This is the latest 22.10 on Ubuntu. I try to always use the latest official release, which is generally snap. Chromium is Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) snap (64-bit). I've added nothing to it.

Comment: Sorry again. Since adding my comment I saw that I had added an extension for Netbeans and Mega. I removed both of the extensions so that now it really is clean. To be sure I did a logout, login. The problem remains unchanged. What I am showing about is a docx which my brother attached for me. However the problem also shows itself on Google docs which I have created. For quite a while I just lived with it until yesterday when I simply couldn't read the attachment I received. That was too much!

Comment: Probably related to hardware acceleration. See if there is a toggle in Chromium settings to disable that. If not, report a bug: bugs.chromium.org.